# Why Entity Framework do not use Inheritance when mapping my DB tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, object-oriented-analysis

I am working on an asp.net mvc web application . and i have mapped my Database tables using EF-6 which created a .tt folder containing my model classes. but i have noted that Entity framework do not define inheritance between the model classes, instead it uses references between classes. for example i have a parent DB table name Technology, and it have child tables such as Server , VM , etc.
now the generated classes look as follow for the Technology & Server:-

```
 public partial class Technology
    {
        public Technology()
        {
            this.Servers = new HashSet<Server>();

        }

        public int TechnologyID { get; set; }
        public string Tag { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
        public byte[] timestamp { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> TypeID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<long> PartialTag { get; set; }
        public bool IsManaged { get; set; }


        public virtual Server Server { get; set; }

        public virtual VirtualMachine VirtualMachine { get; set; }
    }


 public Server()


        public int ServerID { get; set; }
        public int ServerModelID { get; set; }
        public string ILOIP { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> RackID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> StatusID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> BackUpStatusID { get; set; }
        public int RoleID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> OperatingSystemID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> VirtualCenterID { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
        public byte[] timestamp { get; set; }



        public virtual Technology Technology { get; set; }

    }
```

where inside the DB the `Server.ServerID` is a foreign key to the `Technology.TechnologyID`.

so i was expecting that EF will define Technology as a parent object , and Server ,VM will extend (inhirate the Technology). but EF will create a reference for the Technology inside its child .. so what is the idea of using this approach over creating inheritance ?

Answer (score 4):

> so i was expecting that EF will define Technology as a parent object

Yeah. Why?

- You did no bother reading the documentation. It is quite clear how this is done.
- You made an assumpion WITHOUT thinking about the edge cases. If EF would automatically do that, it would do a wrong decision in a LOT of cases.

There is no good automatic way to do this. Because inheritance and inclusion are both often used - so EF can not make an automatic decision. The same way it will not magically make a sensible field for your Tag property (string) because it can not know what a sensible max length is or whether it should allow unicode or not.

Comment: can you explain this in more details please ?

Comment: can you please adivce more why EF will always use composition over inheritance , when mapping DB tables ? i am not saying it is wrong to use composition,, but i am trying to understand how EF works ?

Comment: EF, WITHOUT FURTHER INSTRUCTIONS, will default to composition. It supports inheritance, but it will not make this decision for you.

Comment: so I think the best way is to keep things as is , by having composition between model class which is provided by EF. seems forcing EF to have inheritance instead of composition is a headache and will have performance drawbacks.. so i think i should keep things as is and uses composition.. what do you think on this?

Comment: This is also what I do - but then my data models mostly do not have inheritance to start with (as in: there also is rarely inheritance in the higher level - this is not a meaning I am smarter or dumber, just that when you work with financial transaction data there is really little "real need" for inheritance). I also use database first and my database is highly optimized (i.e. using all SQL Server features, not just the little part that is easily done with Entity Framework).

Answer (score 2):

So you use db first.

Your tables don't have discriminator column. Ef will not recognize them as [TPH](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph).

Your tables have their own primary keys. Ef will not recognize them as [TPT](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt) or [TPC](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines).

<strike>But I didn't test or apply, even your tables exactly fits one of inheritance type, ef may not generate model classes as you expected.</strike>

[TomTom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/285465/tomtom) mentioned in commentes, Ef has default design and will not create inheritance for you on db first.

Comment: so you mean when mapping my DB tables using Entity framework, then the generated classes will not have any inheretance between them is this correct ?

Comment: I say with your design, Ef will not map for sure. But if you change your table design and test you will see it. Child class's primary and foreignkey should be same column and it should be same name as parent class. Your `Server` should have `TechnologyID` as primary key and foreign key.

Comment: ok now let say i change the column name inside the Server to be TechnologyID instead of ServerID .. still the relation between Server & Technology will be a composition relation inside the mapped model classes ,, and not an inheritance ... is this correct ?

Comment: @johnG I said I didn't test it. If you can change and test it.

Comment: no actually i can not find any scenario where EF uses inheritance

Comment: so seems EF will always use composition as per my test .. so now my question is will i get any advantages if i modify how EF mapped my tables to have an inheritance-like model classes? or it is fine to work in the way EF map the model classes by using compositions ?

Comment: No. EF, without instructions by the programmer, always defaults to composition. THis is clearly documented. You can change the behavior, but it is YOU who has to do it.

Comment: @ErkanDemirel It also defaults to that on database first. There is no sensible way to deduct intention by table schema - there are edge cases in both directions where an intelligence must decide what is really wanted. As such, it defaults to not change anything - and databases (at least standard relational ones) do not support inheritance.